# How to mock a method of a class being called inside another method that is being tested of the same class?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

For Example there is a class A with two methods methodUnderTest() and display() where methodUnderTest calls the display method. While writing a junit using mockito how can I mock the display() method?

```
class A{
public int method methodUnderTest{
   //some code
   display();
}

public int display(){
  //some code
}

}
```

Comment: both are public methods

Comment: irrespective of wether it public or private, it need to be tested because its part of class to be tested. if its private then it will be tested through methodUnderTest()

Comment: Have you not tried when(spyA.display()).thenReturn(anyValue)?

Comment: @sandeep private methods can't be mocked with mockito

Comment: Agree, when did i said to mock it. I am saying its not good to mock anything in class that is under test.

Comment: @sandeep please read the question of OP again.

Comment: @madhu I read the question thats why replying. basically what he is tying to do is antipattern.

Comment: @sandeep the OP is just asking about how to mock a method while testing another method. There is no harm in mocking `display` method while testing `methodUnderTest`. That being said, having test for `display` method is necessary too. But that is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need mockito for it. In the test when you create your test object you can create it by

```java
A underTest = new A() {
    @Override
    public int display() {
        return <expected result>
    }
}
```

In this way you can control what kind of value is returned by the display method.

Comment: I used your way and it worked for me. Thanks. However I think the initial downvote was because you did not used Mockito in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If this is your class:

```
    public static class A{
        public int methodUnderTest() {
            return display();
        }

        public int display(){
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

then using mockito, you can do this:

```
        A a = spy(new A());
        when(a.display()).thenReturn(0);
        System.out.println(a.methodUnderTest()); // will print 0
```

Explanation:

When you `mock()` a class, there is no underlying instance, and all the methods you call will do nothing and return default values unless specified otherwise.

When you `spy()` on an instance, all calls get recorded, and **forwarded to the actual instance**. This means that your class behaviour will stay exactly the same unless you mock a specific call.

---

Having said that, a case like yours is usually a symptom that you need to split the class, and invest a bit in [separating your concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: I am testing this code at the moment. Once done, I will accept/comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ty! just FYI, I tested this locally before posting :)

Comment: Any news regarding the testing?

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks for pointing the Spy method to me.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use mockito, I'd go for something like that :

```java
@Spy
private A a;

@Test
public void test() {    
    
    //define the behaviour
    Mockito.when(a.display()).thenReturn(12);
    
    // call methodUnderTest
    int res = a.methodUnderTest();
    
    // check that you get what you want
    Assert.assertEquals(SOME_VALUE, res);
    
}
```

And if you don't want to use annotations, you'd initialize `a` like this :

```java
A a = Mockito.spy(new A());
```

HTH!

Comment: The annotation used in this answer is incorrect. It should be `@Spy` instead of `@Mock`. (But the edit request was rejected).

Comment: @second `@Spy` and `@Mock` both could work but are different things. see https://javapointers.com/tutorial/difference-between-spy-and-mock-in-mockito/

Comment: When you mock `a` the call of `methodUnderTest` is replaced and you get a return of 0, when you spy on `a` the real implementaion of methodUnderTest would be evaluated. As the TO wants to test `methodUnderTest` using Mock is incorrect. You can easily verify that by running your test.

Comment: Realy late but @second was entirely right - I edited the answer accordingly.